# Why do my sound settings not save upon exit in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, technical-issues

When I launch Minecraft, I have to go into the sounds menu and change the music volume level to 0.  When I close Minecraft and reopen it, the sound level will be back at 100.

I am running 1.2.3 (I think).  I am running several mods, but all of them seem to be functioning properly.  I usually play Minecraft with music from my personal music library playing, but I am still able to hear creepers, and other in game sounds.

Is there a way to permanently set the in-game music in Minecraft to 0, or is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste the following Path into the Start menu Search bar (Windows 7) *or* into Windows Explorer, if you are using XP (`Win Key` + `R` => type in the word "explorer" (no quotes) => `Enter`):

```
%appdata%\.minecraft
```

Now open options.txt and edit it to your liking.  The area for music should read:

```
music:0.0
```

If the above Path variable does not work look for this (Windows 7):

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft
```

When you're finished, save the file and set it to read-only, so Minecraft wont change it again.  Right-click options.txt => Properties => Click the Read-only raido button under attributes