# Changes (to controls, video settings, audio, etc) not saving when I close Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've recently noticed that whenever I close my game, any changes I made during the time I was playing do not save. I do not know about vanilla worlds since I play servers only.

I noticed a while back that whenever I tried to activate flame particles, as soon as I close the game they'd become deactivated again. This goes for texture packs too, when I'd deactivate a Hypixel texture pack it would seemingly reenable reenable when I opened the game again.

My friend recently started a 1.16.5 SMP. As a Hypixel player I use 1.8.9 optifine but I want to have more fun so I switched (or at least tried to) to unmodded, no optifine 1.16.5, but it keeps resetting the controls, the video settings, even the "Do not show again" on the third party server warning. For some reason though, my 1.8.9 controls carry over to 1.16.5, even though they didn't carry over when I was still playing 1.14 vanilla (but that was more than a year ago).

I do not have java installed anymore to save space, would that be a problem?

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "I do not have java installed" yes you do, minecraft java edition cant run without it.

Comment: @Topcode I think OP meant they don't have a standalone JRE installed, since Minecraft Java Edition nowadays comes with its own bundled JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the solution to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59911/why-do-my-sound-settings-not-save-upon-exit-in-minecraft?rq=1).

Check out the file permissions for `%appdata%\.minecraft\options.txt` (WIN) or `~/.minecraft/options.txt` (linux). Check if it is opened by any running programs (are there file handles open to it?). When was it last edited? (the `filemtime` attribute).

It could also be that your Minecraft is setting your option changes back on exit. In this case, you could change the options manually and set the file to read-only. The OS will prevent Minecraft from overwriting your changes.

Comment: Uh i tried it but it was last edited a year ago, so thats not a problem. I switched the options.json thing to read-only but it doesnt work, what file are u talking about? Also how do i switch manually?

Comment: Ok, I just realised. The options.txt seems to only be for 1.8.9, since it doesnt have the autoJump and toolbaractivator in the text document. what am i supposed to do about this ;-;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using Lunar Client 1.8.9, and see if it still carries over.
Lunar Client is a ModPack for Minecraft. It is mostly used with hypixel.
Lunar Client saves your 1.8.9 keybinds to a custom file so it won't mess with any other version

https://lunarclient.com

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade! Sadly, answers being just 'Use X' are often not well received. Like for someone who doesn't know what Lunar Client is, how do you know, without going the rabbit hole of 'What the hell is Lunar Client' that this solution would work. So if you could edit your answer and tell us why changing clients would fix the issue, that would make for a good answer. Have a nice day!